# Fill array with elements at certain positions

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

Given is a `std::array` which contains instances of sub classes of `IMyClass`:

```
std::array<std::shared_ptr<IMyClass>, 20> myArr;
```

At index position 0, 5 and 10

```
std::make_shared<RareSubClass>()
```

should be assigned, on all other indices

```
std::make_shared<FrequentSubClass>()
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: How will the indices be provided for those elements that need to become `RareSubClass`? Is it hardcoded?

Comment: Are you OK with runtime initialization?

Comment: @AndyG Yes, RareSubClass instances are always at the mentioned positions.

Comment: @user1056903: Then probably doing uniform initialization is best. `std::array<...> myArr = {make_shared<FrequentSubClass>(), make_shared<RareSubClass>(), ...};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to initialize that array at runtime using a small helper function:

```
 void init_array(std::array<std::shared_ptr<IMyClass>, 20>& arr) {
      int slot = 0;
      for(auto& subclass : arr) {
         switch(slot) {
         case 0:
         case 5:
         case 10:
             subClass = std::make_shared<RareSubClass>();
             break;
         default:
             subClass = std::make_shared<FrequentSubClass>();
             break;
         }
         ++slot;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thx! I used the loop variable for the current array position.

Comment: @user Since it's `std::array` and everything is deducible at compile time I could even think of a meta-programming solution using a variadic template class taking the `0,5,10` parameters. But I doubt it's worth the efforts so far (would be an interesting experiment though).